# what is the lightest data in json? boolean or integer (1 or 0)

Tags: json

I need to send data in the lightest way possible, so I need to know what is lighter: To send boolean data as boolean `true` or `false` or send it as numeric `1` or `0`.

I know they are 2 different data types, but in code I could send the boolean data as integer (`1` or `0`) and when I receive, I could convert it back to boolean. I would like to know what is lightest way.

Answer (score 4):

JSON is **textual** data format. That means the value `true` will need four characters (maybe 4 bytes) while the value `0` only needs one character (1 byte).

However, the difference is probably negligible if you gzip the JSON document, which you should certainly do if possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways of understanding "lightest":

1. Notational - true/false it's **4 chars**
2. Treated as Object (by interpreter's JSON parsers) - **in memory** true/false is **1 bit**
3. Transportational - when You want to send JSON object through **network protocol** You have to **serialize** it, in this case true/false is **4 chars** also

```js
var data = {
  boolFalse: false,
  numericFalse: 0,
  boolTrue: true,
  numericTrue: 1
};

var stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log('THIS IS JSON OBJECT:', data);

console.log('THIS IS STRINGIFIED JSON OBJECT:', stringifiedData);
```

p.s. if You have huge JSON object and You want the lightest realization on network traffic so take a look at [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) format, and find BSON libs (example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson)

Comment: JSON is a textual data format. `true` and `false` are represented as a character sequences, not just a single bit. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-3 .

Comment: @FelixKling I understand what You mean, but how about JSON parsers in browser? Are all of them treat true/false as boolean (1 bit) or no? Because when You take object and do like: if(data.boolTrue === true) it returns true

Comment: Are you maybe talking about JavaScript objects? That's completely separate from JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, that's what I mean about notation vs objects. In notation You can type 4 chars, but actually they are converted to object values. I think question is not exact, "lightest" can be on 2 levels: notational vs converted to object

Comment: Well, JavaScript object *literals* are still different from JSON. Their syntax may look similar but it's really two different things. Of course JavaScript being an actual programming language, the values are represented differently in memory (but how depends the JS engine).

Comment: @FelixKling I've changed my answer, feel free to fix me if I'm wrong. Thx (:

Comment: "in memory true/false is 1 bit" --- not sure any language can automatically optimise it to be less than 1 byte. "THIS IS JSON OBJECT" --- there is no such thing as "json object" http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @zerkms I understand what You mean, but ideally most languages try to be efficient. So, yes, it's not only 1 bit if we think about how it keeps in memory, but data itself it's 1 bit

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have answered your won question. In any kind of programming/code, binary (0 and 1) is the lightest form of data you could have.

If your question however is which is lighter between 0 and 1, judging by the fact that "0" has a lower ASCII value than "1", I will say 0. But this will still depend on the type of encoding used.

I advice you send your data as 0 or 1. If you need a true-false value, you could always compare 0 and 1 just like you would do to boolean.

In its pure nature, True and False will finally get represented as 0 and 1.

Plus 0 and 1 really keep your JSON data shorter than using True-False. Except the data is coming from a server compressed using GZIP, in which case size difference may be negligible.